# Discord.py :- AttributeError: module 'music' has no attribute 'setup'

Tags: python, module, discord, bots, attributeerror

I am getting this error in my main file. I have tried using music docs but it is not working out as I cannot see the setup attribute in the music library of python.

Comment: Please post code and error messages so we can help you better.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.